# Handling different length digits in datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Using the following code i am reading a csv file into a dataframe and convert the time column 'object' into a 'datetime' format.

```
# Use the read_csv function to create a DataFrame from the CSV file
shackles = pd.read_csv(path_data_shackles, delimiter=';')
print(shackles.dtypes)

# Convert time column to datetime column
shackles['time'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(shackles['time']), format="%H:%M:%S:%f")

print('')
print(shackles['time'].iloc[3688])
print('')

print(shackles.dtypes)
```

Which outputs the following:

```
DataTag       object
ms_Elapsed     int64
Value         object
time          object
dtype: object

2023-05-02 10:54:00.760000

DataTag               object
ms_Elapsed             int64
Value                 object
time          datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

**The problem** is that it reads 10:54:00:76 as 10:54:00:**760** instead of 10:54:00:**076**.
Which causes my graph to look weird as shown in the picture.

[image]

**I tried** converting the time column into a string column first so i can fill zeros infront of the digits to make it 3 digits total.However i was unable to convert it into a string column in the first place. Someone got any other idea's on how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pre-process your string with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and [`zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) to correctly pad the last digits:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(
               df['time'].str.replace('(\d+)$', lambda m: m.group(1).zfill(3),
                                      regex=True),
               format='%H:%M:%S:%f')
```

Alternatively, with [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
tmp = df['time'].str.rsplit(':', n=1, expand=True)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(tmp[0]+':'+tmp[1].str.zfill(3), format='%H:%M:%S:%f')
```

Example output:

```
0   1900-01-01 10:54:00.076
1   1900-01-01 10:54:00.252
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['10:54:00:76', '10:54:00:252']})
```

Comment: Thanks! The first options worked perfectly! Spending 2 hours without results and you solve it within minutes, amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works:

```
shackles['time'] = pd.to_datetime(shackles['time'], format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S:%f")
shackles['time'] = shackles['time'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

print(shackles['time'].iloc[3688])
```

Comment: Option didn't work, thanks anyway!